# Generic Web handler ashx parameters

Tags: web-development, website-design

I recently found a link from a stock market website which allows me to download my raw stock data from it:

```
http://www.example.com/StocksHandler.ashx?{%22Type%22:%22ALL2%22,%20%22Lan%22:%22En%22}
```

But I'm interesting to know if I could change the parameters (in the link) to filter downloadable data? For example I may just need "BestBuyPrice" of every stock not more information; can I change link to reduce downloaded data?
How can I find out what parameters are available and defined by the web designer? Is there any scanner for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `{%22Type%22:%22ALL2%22,%20%22Lan%22:%22En%22}`

This looks like an encoded JSON string (the `%22` is an escaped `"`), representing:

```
Type = All
Language = English
```

> can I change link to reduce downloaded data?

Possibly. The `Type` parameter looks promising.

> How can I find out what parameters are available and defined by the web designer?

Contact the site that is providing this service. Do they provide any documentation? Experiment by creating other reports and see how the parameters/URL vary.

This information is likely to be unique to the service, so this information needs to come from them. (Although the `Lan` parameter would seem to be self-explanatory, the precise values that are permitted are still likely to be site specific.)

> Is there any scanner for this?

I doubt it.